# C# Check if list<t> contains any of another list and return the matching item

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list of strings that I need to find/verify in another list of strings and return those that are found.

```
List<string> strList1 = new List<string>() { "oranges", "apples", "grapes" };
List<string> strList2 = new List<string>() {
   "Joe likes peaches",
   "Mack likes apples",
   "Hank likes raisins",
   "Jodi likes grapes",
   "Susan likes apples"  
};
```

OK, so this is a bad example but, basically, I want to be able to create a Linq call to find any value in `strList1` in one or more elements in `strList2` and return which ones were found.

So the results would be a list of `strList1` items found in ````strList2```. Something like:

```
List<string> found = { "apples", "grapes" };
```

My searching hasn't resulted in anything because I'm probably not searching correctly.  Any help would be great appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: In the most straightforward way: `var found = strList1.Where(word => strList2.Any(sentence => sentence.Contains(word))).ToList()`. Note that this is a quadratic algorithm that tests every combination in the worst case; depending on what list(s) we expect to be big and how long our "words" are more efficient approaches are possible (with things like dedicated full-text indexing at the extreme end). [String-searching algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm) are a big topic in computing.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert, the lists should be very long at all but I will take up your advice to study up more on string-searching algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this will answer your question

`strList1.Where(c => strList2.Any(a => a.Contains(c))).ToList();`

Comment: Thanks, I had tried a variation of this and it originally didn't work.  The problem was that, when I originally put your code in above,  **ReSharper** suggested that I replace the "Contains" portion with "method group".  This changed it to ```strList1.Where(c => strList2.Any(c.Contains)).ToList();``` and that failed!  Thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: @MarkLinebarger That changes the logic and would be incorrect. That's checking whether words in `strList1` contain a sentence in `strList2`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't guarantee performance, but this can be accomplished using [Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0) and [Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-6.0).

```
strList1.Where(str => strList2.Any(str2.Contains(str)))
```

Or for complex objects:

```
objList1.Where(obj => objList2.Any(obj2.property.Contains(obj.property)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do it. Doing linq you could benefit of `Intersect`, if you first split the "sentences" to "words".

```
List<string> strList1 = new List<string>() { "oranges", "apples", "grapes" };
List<string> strList2 = new List<string>() {
   "Joe likes peaches",
   "Mack likes apples",
   "Hank likes raisins",
   "Jodi likes grapes",
   "Susan likes apples"  
};

List<string> found = strList1.Intersect(strList2.SelectMany(s => s.Split(" "))).ToList();
```